# C++ Memory HoughLinesP

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

I made a program using HoughLinesP and now it just stuck when comes to 17th frame, it is running something but no results. Using another video it get stuck on 13th frame (that is the moment when object come into the video). I think that is a memory problem, but I have cleaning all vectors as I found on forum. Also I found something similar and solution is :

> Linking your application against the same CRT as your OpenCV library version does

I don't understand how to do that, I am using MSVC 2013, Update 4. There is my code:

```
 struct myclass {
   bool operator() (Vec4i l1, Vec4i l2) { return (l1[0] < l2[0]); }
 } myobjectv;

struct myclass1 {
    bool operator() (Vec4i l1, Vec4i l2) { return (l1[1] < l2[1]); }
} myobjecth;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

vector<Rect*> components(250, (Rect *)NULL);
VideoCapture video1;
int vektor, ukupno_komponenti;
int width, height, frames1, fps1;
video1.open(argv[1]);
fps1 = video1.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
width = video1.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
height = video1.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
frames1 = video1.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
Mat src, dst, cdst, krug;
Mat frameTime1(height, width, CV_8UC3, Scalar(0, 0, 0));
int fvd = 0;
while (1)
{
    fvd++;
    cout << fvd;
    video1 >> src;
    bool bSuccess = video1.read(src);
    if (!bSuccess) //if not success, break loop
    {
        cout << "ERROR: Cannot read a frame from video file" << endl;
        break;
    }
    Mat roi_w1;
    roi_w1 = src(Rect(150, 50, 320, 320));
    GaussianBlur(roi_w1, roi_w1, Size(11, 11), 0);
    Canny(roi_w1, dst, 50, 200, 3);
    cvtColor(dst, cdst, CV_GRAY2BGR);

    vector<Vec4i> lines;
    vector<Vec4i> h_lines;
    vector<Vec4i> v_lines;

    HoughLinesP(dst, lines, 1, CV_PI / 220, 50, 150, 30);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++)
    {
        Vec4i l = lines[i];
        double Angle = atan2(l[3] - l[1], l[2] - l[0]) * 180.0 / CV_PI;
        if (Angle < 0) Angle = Angle + 360;
        //vertikalne
        if ((abs(Angle) > 88) | (abs(Angle) == 90)){
            v_lines.push_back(lines[i]);

        }
        //horizontalne
        if ((abs(Angle) == 0) | (abs(Angle) < 2)){
            h_lines.push_back(lines[i]);
        }

    }
    int broj[10] = { 0 };
    sort(v_lines.begin(), v_lines.end(), myobjectv);
    vector<Vec4i> vv_lines;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v_lines.size() - 1; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = i + 1; j < v_lines.size(); j++)
        {
            Vec4i l1 = v_lines[i];
            Vec4i l2 = v_lines[j];
            if ((abs(l1[2] - l2[2]) < 20)){
                if ((broj[i] == 0) && (broj[j] == 0))
                {
                    vv_lines.push_back(l1);
                    broj[i]++;
                    broj[j]++;
                }
            }
            else{
                if ((broj[i] == 0)){ vv_lines.push_back(l1); }
                if ((broj[j] == 0)){ vv_lines.push_back(l2); }
            }
        }
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < vv_lines.size(); i++)
    {
        Vec4i lcr = vv_lines[i];
        line(cdst, Point(lcr[0], lcr[1]), Point(lcr[2], lcr[3]), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 3, CV_AA);
    }
    int brojb[10] = { 0 };
    sort(h_lines.begin(), h_lines.end(), myobjecth);
    vector<Vec4i> hh_lines;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < h_lines.size(); i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = i; j < h_lines.size() - 1; j++)
        {
            Vec4i l1 = h_lines[i];
            Vec4i l2 = h_lines[j];
            if ((abs(l1[1] - l2[1]) < 20)){
                if ((brojb[i] == 0) && (brojb[j] == 0))
                {
                    hh_lines.push_back(l1);
                    brojb[i]++;
                    brojb[j]++;
                }

            }
            else{
                if ((brojb[i] == 0)){ hh_lines.push_back(l1); }
                if ((brojb[j] == 0)){ hh_lines.push_back(l2); }

            }
        }
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < hh_lines.size(); i++)
    {
        Vec4i lcr = hh_lines[i];
        line(cdst, Point(lcr[0], lcr[1]), Point(lcr[2], lcr[3]), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 3, CV_AA);
    }

    vector<Point> grid;
    Point P;
    int s = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < hh_lines.size(); i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < vv_lines.size(); j++)
        {
            Vec4i lb1 = hh_lines[i];
            Vec4i lb2 = vv_lines[j];
            float p1startx = lb1[0];
            float p1starty = lb1[1];
            float p1endx = lb1[2];
            float p1endy = lb1[3];
            float p2startx = lb2[0];
            float p2starty = lb2[1];
            float p2endx = lb2[2];
            float p2endy = lb2[3];

            if ((p2startx>p1startx)&(p2startx < p1endx)){
                P.x = p2startx;
                P.y = p1starty;
                grid.push_back(P);
                circle(cdst, P, 3, Scalar(0, 0, 255), -1, 8, 0);
                s++;

            }
        }
    }

    vector<Vec4i>().swap(lines);
    vector<Vec4i>().swap(h_lines);
    vector<Vec4i>().swap(hh_lines);
    vector<Vec4i>().swap(v_lines);
    vector<Vec4i>().swap(vv_lines);
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by stuck ? The program crashes ? Did you try a debugger to see where the problem occurs ?

Comment: Thank you, I found what is the problem while checking in which line is problem. In one part it doesn't find any vertical line and it is loop ( i=0,i<size which is zero )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is probably here:

```
if ((abs(Angle) > 88) | (abs(Angle) == 90))
{
    v_lines.push_back(lines[i]);
}
//horizontalne
if ((abs(Angle) == 0) | (abs(Angle) < 2))
{
    h_lines.push_back(lines[i]);
}
```

You need to use Logical OR (`||`) operator, and not bitwise OR (`|`), which you are mistakenly using.

```
if ((abs(Angle) > 88) || (abs(Angle) == 90))
{
    ...
}
if ((abs(Angle) == 0) || (abs(Angle) < 2))
{
    ...
}
```